Google Play Protect Warning: "This app tries to spy on your personal data, such as SMS messages, photos or call history." How to Resolve?
I'm encountering a serious issue with my app on the Google Play Store. After uploading my app, users are receiving the following Google Play Protect warning:

"This app tries to spy on your personal data, such as SMS messages, photos, audio recordings, or call history."

My app requires the following permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.avodigy.eventpediago.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.avodigy.eventpediago.permission.UA_DATA" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" />

Issue:
Despite my app's functionality requiring some of these permissions, I want to ensure it is not flagged as spyware by Google Play Protect. I understand that some permissions like GET_ACCOUNTS, MANAGE_ACCOUNTS, and RECORD_AUDIO can be particularly sensitive.
Steps Taken:

Permissions Review: Removed unnecessary permissions.
Runtime Permissions: Implemented runtime requests for sensitive permissions.
Transparency: Added explanations in the app for why each permission is needed.
Privacy Policy: Updated to clearly explain the use of each permission.

Question:
How can I resolve this Google Play Protect warning and ensure my app is compliant with Google's security policies? Are there any specific practices or checks I should perform to avoid my app being flagged as spyware?
Additional Information:

The app accesses location data for event recommendations.
The camera and microphone are used for profile pictures and audio notes.
External storage is accessed for media uploads.
Accounts are managed for user authentication and synchronization.

Any help or guidance on how to address this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Permissions Review: Removed unnecessary permissions.
Runtime Permissions: Implemented runtime requests for sensitive permissions.
Transparency: Added explanations in the app for why each permission is needed.
Privacy Policy: Updated to clearly explain the use of each permission.


Can you post the updated android manifest file after removing unnecessary permissions?
